# Excel Geomean returns #value! sometimes?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've modified the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) function below to suit my needs.

I have many workbooks with sheets that contain 4500+ rows, and I use the function to search for two given values (as boundaries). Then, it selects the rows as the range. Finally, do whatever on that range. The function:

```
Function GeoM(A, B)

Application.Volatile    
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rng As Range

x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(A, Range("B:B"), 0) ' looking in col B
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(B, Range("B:B"), 0) ' looking in col B

Set rng = Range(Cells(x, 18), Cells(y, 18)) 'Im working on col 18
GeoM = Application.WorksheetFunction.GeoMean(rng)
End Function
```

The problem is, this code works just fine except with `GeoMean`n. I noticed when the range of data is relatively small (number of data cells) it returns a value. However, if the range is larger than approx. 126 cells, it returns `#value!`.

I'm stuck and working on solving this issue. Is the `GeoMean` function limited to a given number of data?

Thanks

Comment: what Excel version? Is your `rng` variable valid beforecalculting `GeoM`?

Comment: Excel 2007. And yes, It returns values if the cells approx. 126 or less. If the range is more than 126 it returns #value!. I use the same code with functions other than geomean and it works. that's why I'm confused and started thinking that there's something limiting the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a 170 character limit on my testing for earlier Excel versions (I tested in xl03), validated in this [Mr Excel thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/2042-geomean.html)

*(Xl10 worked fine on the longer dataset)*

I also tried:

- Using `Evaluate`
- Using a 1D array

**failed samples**

```
Dim X
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A171")
MsgBox Evaluate("GeoMean(A1:A171)")
X = Application.Transpose(rng1)
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.GeoMean(X)
```

to no avail.

So I think your two workarounds are either:

1. Inserting a formula via VBA into Excel and using this result
2. As per the MrExcel thread use the derivation of `GeoMean`, ie `=EXP(AVERAGE(LN(Range)))`

**Suggested Approach**

```
MsgBox Evaluate("EXP(AVERAGE(LN(A1:A171)))")
```

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, I've started working on after my previous comment I'll post the fix now. Thanks again, I appricate your efforts.

Comment: I guess I need to wait 7 hrs to post the fixed function Haha :D. I hope I dont forget to do so.

Comment: Did you use the approach I suggested?

Comment: +1 Dave - I think that the limitation isn't the number of values but when the product of the values exceeds the max value excel can handle in a formula [1.7976931348623158e+308] - also mentioned by `Mark W` in MrExcel thread - that value hasn't changed from 2003 to 2013 - you can verify by using `PRODUCT` function on the same data - it will fail whenever `GEOMEAN` fails

Comment: @barryhoudini Hi barry, I am running a test using `=ROW()` from `A1` down to `A200`, in *xl03* `=GEOMEAN(A1:A200)` fails as a regular formula  (as does the `PRODUCT` test you mentioned), **but** in *xl10* `=GEOMEAN(A1:A200)` works for me, but `=PRODUCT(A1:A200)` fails

Comment: Thanks Dave - I clearly didn't test well enough.....! I don't have 2003 but in 2007 PRODUCT and GEOMEAN fail at the same point, but now I see that that doesn't happen in 2010 and 2013 - presumably MS have altered the GEOMEAN calc method in Excel 2010 onwards....

Comment: Interesting isn't it to see the differences between xl versions. 'IRR' can even give a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `brettdj`, I fixed the function and it works now:

```
Function GeoM(A, B)

Application.Volatile
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim LnValue As Double
Dim count As Integer

x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(A, Range("B:B"), 0) 'look in col. B
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(B, Range("B:B"), 0) 'look in col. B

Set rng = Range(Cells(x, 18), Cells(y, 18)) 'set range of rows on col# 18

Do
  LnValue = LnValue + Math.Log(Cells(x, 18)) 'calculates sum of ln(value)
  x = x + 1
  count = count + 1   'calculates the total number of values
Loop Until x > y      'stop when x (upper row#) is greater than y (lower row#)

GeoM = Math.Exp((1 / count) * LnValue) 'GeoMean formula

End Function
```

This function searches a specified column for two values as upper and lower limits (Note: that means you shouldn't have repeated values in that column. In another words, the column should have unique values). Then, it finds the `GeoMean` of the values on other column, which has values fall in the same range of rows.